# flutter: `RouteAware.didPop()` not triggered using `PageView.animateToPage()`

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation

I'm working on page navigation, but noticed that swipe gesture `PageView.animateToPage()` does not trigger `RouteAware` callback `didPop()` when I leave a page, only `didPush()` gets called for the new page.

### Expectation

When I implement a `Drawer`, calling

```dart
Navigator.of(context).pop();
```

in the drawer triggers `didPop()` as expected.

So I expect that as a higher-level API, `PageView` would encapsulate this well.
But so far I only see `onPageChanged(index)` but this would be similar to `didPush()` unless I manage the index as a state myself.

### Question

Is this by design?